# Letsencrypt unable to verify the domain

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt

I have the following config working:

```
upstream app_admin {
 server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  server_name admin.test.com;

  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://app_admin;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

    # for Let's Encrypt to work properly
    location ^~ /.well-known {
        root /var/www/;
        default_type "text/plain";
        allow all;
    }
}
```

I installed Letsencrypt and ran this command, but I get errors:

/opt/letsencrypt# ./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www -d admin.test.com

> Performing the following challenges:
>   http-01 challenge for admin.test.com
>   Using the webroot path /var/www for all unmatched domains.
>   Waiting for verification...
>   Cleaning up challenges
>   Failed authorization procedure. admin.test.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching http://admin.test.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/zlmdu1lWhUxZdwyV_1Kf--vgzEM6ETXr_qZzwR4uf6pM: Timeout
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>    - The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: admin.test.com
>      Type:   connection
>      Detail: Fetching
>      http://admin.test.com /.well-known/acme-challenge/zlmdu1lWhUbfdwyV_1Kf--vgzEM6ETXr_qZytfR4I6pM:
>      Timeout
>
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>      entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
>      contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
>      your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
>      firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
>      client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
>      that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.

I can get to my site by going to admin.test.com without issues.

---

EDIT1:

With this command, I got the following:

$ ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone

> Please enter in your domain name(s) (comma and/or space separated)  (Enter 'c'
>   to cancel):admin.test.com
>
> Obtaining a new certificate
>   Performing the following challenges:
>   tls-sni-01 challenge for admin.test.com
>   Waiting for verification...
>   Cleaning up challenges
>   Failed authorization procedure. admin.test.com (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Timeout
>   Preformatted text

Again, I CAN get to my site with: admin.test.com (port 80).

Looking at the bottom of the log

/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
>   2017-06-29 03:09:34,776:INFO:certbot.auth_handler:Cleaning up challenges
>   2017-06-29 03:09:34,777:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.standalone:Stopping server at :::443...
>   2017-06-29 03:09:35,014:DEBUG:certbot.log:Exiting abnormally:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>     File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 743, in main
>       return config.func(config, plugins)
>     File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 683, in certonly
>       lineage = _get_and_save_cert(le_client, config, domains, certname, lineage)
>     File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 82, in _get_and_save_cert
>       lineage = le_client.obtain_and_enroll_certificate(domains, certname)
>     File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/client.py", line 344, in obtain_and_enroll_certificate
>       certr, chain, key, _ = self.obtain_certificate(domains)
>     File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/client.py", line 313, in obtain_certificate
>       self.config.allow_subset_of_names)
>     File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 81, in get_authorizations
>       self._respond(resp, best_effort)
>     File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 138, in _respond
>       self._poll_challenges(chall_update, best_effort)
>     File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 202, in _poll_challenges
>       raise errors.FailedChallenges(all_failed_achalls)
>   FailedChallenges: Failed authorization procedure. admin.test.com (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Timeout

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The fact that *you* can connect to your server isn't important.  Can your site be accessed from the Internet? What about those `/.well-known/...` paths? What happens when you try to access those from elsewhere?  Also, I suspect the hostname in the question isn't yours.  Don't use other people's domain names, please.  See http://example.com.

Comment: I figured out that I had the ports blocked outside my box.  :D

Comment: I also used `ec2`, `ubuntu`, `nginx` and  faced similar problem, my problem was solved by adding inbound rule `HTTPS` for port number `443`.